# Spring boot 2.1 application not able to publish traces to Spring boot 1.5 Zipkin server

Tags: maven, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-sleuth, zipkin

I'm working on a spring boot application version 2.1.2 with below dependency

```
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
<version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
```

The application is not able to send the traces to Zipkin server which is running on Spring boot 1.5.

When I tried downgrading my application to Spring 1.5 it started sending traces to the Zipkin server.

Can someone please assist. Am I missing any configuration for Spring boot 2.1?

Below are the dependency & configuration for Spring cloud Sleuth and Starter Zipkin

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>


<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-zipkin</artifactId>
</dependency>


sleuth:
   sampler:
     probability: 1.0
zipkin:
   baseUrl: "Zipkin Server URL
   enabled: true
```

Answer (score 0):

I got same problem. Seem Spring boot **2.1.2.RELEASE** not work with Zipkin. Please upgrade to Spring boot version > **2.1.2.RELEASE**.